# Unable to get cronjob working with Magento2.4

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.4, crontab

Running Magento 2.4.

After installing Magento I get the following error in the admin panel:

```
One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running.
```

I've logged into SSH as Magento user (non root). I've ran the following:

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Which produces ...

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index exception: Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

I cleared cache, yet the problem still exists.

I've ran `bin/magento cron:install` and my crontab looks like so:

```
#~ MAGENTO START 663d4cebd52acc169f7992767d6661404ecce65ca58a220ba7b032ca1dc11162
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.4 /var/www/html/mage/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/mage/var/log/magento.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END 663d4cebd52acc169f7992767d6661404ecce65ca58a220ba7b032ca1dc11162
```

I've also directly ran `/usr/bin/php7.4 /var/www/html/mage/bin/magento cron:run` to confirm everything is working and it produces: `Ran jobs by schedule`.

Yet when I log into admin panel the message is still there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your search index failed:

```
Catalog Search index exception: Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

That error means Magento can’t connect to your elasticsearch instance. Check or configure your elasticsearch settings in Configuration > Catalog > Search Engine and test your connection and then try reindexing again.

Comment: I already have elastic search installed. But, the service was stopped. Running `systemctl start elasticsearch` seems to take an age to load. Edit: Nope, I get `Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.`

Comment: It turns out I needed more memory for elasticsearch. After that it worked. Thank you.